# Laravel Dusk, select dropdown not populated

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I have a contact page where a `select` dropdown contains the kind of assistance required. The dropdown is correctly populated if I browse to that page through my browser (any browser: Firefox, Chrome, Edge...), but trying to browse the page using Laravel Dusk for testing purposes the dropdown is empty.

This is the test class

```php
class ContactTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations, DatabaseTransactions;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->artisan('db:seed');
    }

    /**
     * @test
     * @throws Throwable
     */
    public function send_a_contact_message()
    {
        // check if the types' table is populated
        // this test passes, then the table is populated
        $this->assertDatabaseHas( 'contact_types', [
            'name' => 'info'
        ] );

        // fill and submit the form
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('/contact')
                ->select('type', 'info')
                ->type('#c_email', 'alhazred@local.test')
                ->type('object', 'Contact test')
                ->type('message', 'Contact test text message')
                ->click('#confirm_btn');
        });

        // check if an entry has been stored into the database
        // this test fails saying that the table is empty
        $this->assertDatabaseHas( 'contact_messages', [
            'type' => 'info',
            'email' => 'alhazred@local.test',
            'object' => 'Contact test',
            'message' => 'Contact test text message'
        ] );
    }
}
```

This is the `create()` function inside the `ContactMessagesController`

```php
public function create()
{
    $msg_types = ContactType::all()->sortBy('id');

    $types = [];
    foreach ($msg_types as $msg_type)
    {
        $types[$msg_type->name] = trans('contact.type_'.$msg_type->name);
    }

    return view('contact_us', compact('types'));
}
```

This is how I create the dropdown inside the view

```php
<select name="type" id="type" class="custom-select">
    @foreach($types as $id => $text)
        <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $text }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

I'm sure that the problem is the dropdown not filled because I've put the line `dd($types);` inside the `create()` function just before the `return` and the screenshot taken by Dusk on failure shows an empty array, while browsing there manually the filled array is shown.

Also this assertion fails

```php
$browser->visit('/contact')
    ->assertSee('General Information');
```

where `General Information` is the text which should be shown for the `info` type, which confirms that the dropdown is not populated.

What could be the reason why the dropdown is populated when the page is reached with a regular browser, but not using Dusk?

Laravel 5.8 - Dusk 5 - PHP 7.2.14

Comment: I've just noticed that removing the `DatabaseTransactions` all the tests pass, but I don't get the reason.

Comment: Dusk tests don't work with `DatabaseTransactions`: https://laravel.com/docs/dusk#migrations